# How to make drop-down menu view as vertical?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```css
site-nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0.8em 2em 0 0;
    opacity: .95;
    background: none;
  }

 .site-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

 .drop-down {
    display: none;
  }

 ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    background-color: rgba(1,80,114,0.50);
    height: 9em;
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PAVEIKTIE DARBI</a></li>
                <li class="pakalp"><a href="#">PAKALPOJUMI</a>
                    <ul class="drop-down">
                        <li><a href="#">ĢENERĀLUZŅĒMĒJS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROJEKTU VADĪBA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROJEKTĒŠANA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BŪVDARBU VADĪBA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MONTĀŽA</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">INŽENIERTEHNISKĀS SISTĒMAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KONTAKTI</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I've been making this web-page for my new business, and I'm stuck with navigation bar - I can't make it drop as a vertical list. Instead it shows as flex. I wrota a lot of code and clearly messed up somewhere, but I can't find where exactly. Tried everything I could find on the internet (didn't check the dark web though), but I can't fix it.

Here is my CSS

```
.site-nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0.8em 2em 0 0;
    opacity: .95;
    background: none;
  }

 .site-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

 .drop-down {
    display: none;
  }

 ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    background-color: rgba(1,80,114,0.50);
    height: 9em;
```

Here is my HTML

```
<nav class="site-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PAVEIKTIE DARBI</a></li>
                <li class="pakalp"><a href="#">PAKALPOJUMI</a>
                    <ul class="drop-down">
                        <li><a href="#">ĢENERĀLUZŅĒMĒJS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROJEKTU VADĪBA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROJEKTĒŠANA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BŪVDARBU VADĪBA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MONTĀŽA</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">INŽENIERTEHNISKĀS SISTĒMAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KONTAKTI</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Change your <li> display: block; not inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not make your `<li>` inline block display.

```
.site-nav > ul > li{
   /* This makes the outer ul li elements  horizontal*/
   .display: inline-block;
}

 ul.drop-down li {
    /* This makes the inside ul li to be stacked*/
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Problem is, if I change display back to block, it just stacks in one vertical pile at the right corner, but I need the navigation bar horizontal, and drop-down menu vertical. How could I do that?

Comment: Try the updated Code. The main problem in your code is that you're target all ui li elements with your styling. So try to target ourter ul first and then target the inner ul. Outer ul li must be inline-block, and dropdown ul li must be block display. that will give you the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You need to make some adjustments to your CSS regarding the `.dropdown` class.

You can read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here we mainly set the following flexbox properties for our `.dropdown` class to get the desired behaviour:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; 
justify-content: space-around;
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwqwOd

```css
.site-nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0.8em 2em 0 0;
  opacity: 0.95;
  background: none;
}

.site-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.drop-down {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.site-nav > ul > li:hover .drop-down {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(1, 80, 114, 0.5);
  height: 9em;
}

.site-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```